Jenkins not picking up AWS credentials in job properly
I've got Jenkins installed on an ec2 on AWS. I can SSH int the ec2 as the ec2-user and run the following without issue. (I'll list the test.js file below but is very simple)
aws configure list
node --version
npm --version

aws s3 ls

node test.js

When I setup a Jenkins job with an "Execute Shell" Build Step and run those same commands it fails when running node. (I've recreated the test.js and node modules in the jenkins workspace).
06:09:48 + aws configure list
06:09:49       Name                    Value             Type    Location
06:09:49       ----                    -----             ----    --------
06:09:49    profile                <not set>             None    None
06:09:49 access_key     ****************ZGQC         iam-role    
06:09:49 secret_key     ****************E69U         iam-role    
06:09:49     region                us-west-2             imds    
06:09:49 + node --version
06:09:49 v18.17.0
06:09:49 + npm --version
06:09:49 9.6.7
06:09:49 + aws s3 ls
06:09:50 2020-06-25 20:18:09 bucket-1
06:09:50 2020-06-25 22:27:28 bucket-2
06:09:50 + node test.js
06:09:50 null
06:09:50 SyntaxError [CredentialsError]: Missing credentials in config
06:09:50     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
06:09:50     at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sagely-calendar-print/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/metadata_service.js:115:38
06:09:50     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sagely-calendar-print/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/metadata_service.js:74:45)
06:09:50     at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:526:35)
06:09:50     at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
06:09:50     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
06:09:50     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
06:09:50   code: 'CredentialsError',
06:09:50   time: 2024-04-26T16:09:50.815Z,
06:09:50   originalError: {
06:09:50     message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
06:09:50     code: 'CredentialsError',
06:09:50     time: 2024-04-26T16:09:50.815Z,
06:09:50     originalError: { message: 'Unexpected end of JSON input' }
06:09:50   }
06:09:50 }
06:09:50 ERROR: Build step failed with exception

The EC2 is getting the credentials from an attached IAM role on the ec2. What is the jenkins node environment missing that it can't pickup the system's credentials?
The node script:
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
S3.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
});


Add the pipeline config. Is it a Freestyle? Screenshot the relevant parts.

@Iterokun - The config is at the ec2 level not Jenkins. It should work regardless of user or config. But this is just a single job with a single Build Step  that is an Execute Shell with the above commands in it.

Add env | sort to both and compare.

@Iterokun - There are no environment variables for AWS at all for either account. My issue is the the AWS CLI works under Jenkins, it can get the credentials as seen in the logs in the post above. But node can't.

Something tells node to do something different. Either an env variable or a stray config file.

check if the jenkins is running as a different user, and that user might not be having aws creds file in its home directory?
Also, try using jenkins credentials plugin for such scenarios and avoid having it on EC2

@SurendraDeshpande - The credentials are system wide, from an IAM role. There re no credentials in any home directory.
